# how to display list through backboneview?

Tags: backbone.js

This is my first backbone code :)

How can I display my list here:

```
<title>list</title>
<ul id="container">
    <li>
        <%- name %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
  var app = {}; // create namespace for our app

        app.Mymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:
        {
            name: ''
        }
        });

        app.List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: app.Mymodel,
            localStorage:new Store('vandaag')
        });

        // renders individual todo items list (li)
        app.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#container',
            initialize: function () {
                app.list = new app.List();
                app.list.add({ name: 'piet' });
                app.list.add({ name: 'ed' });
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){
                this.$el.append(app.list);

                //var view = new app.MyView({ model: new app.Mymodel({name:'ed',city:'ny'}));
                //$('#todo-list').append(view.render().el);
            }
        });

        app.myView = new app.MyView();
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/YBPG6/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First have your template created. In below fiddle it is template with ID `list-template`.
Then you can compile the template, add data to it and render the view.
Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YBPG6/4/) updated fiddle.

To know how Underscore Templates work try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/underscore-template-editor/launch).